# Are all Ubuntu apps the same on every device

Tags: application-development, macbook

Bit of a newbie question Are all Ubuntu apps the same regardless of the device for instance if I made an app for Ubuntu on a jetson tx2 developer kit would the code be same as a Ubuntu app ran on a MacBook?

Comment: The Jetson TX2 has an ARM CPU, and the MacBook has an Intel CPU.

Comment: In most cases yes with no to little additional effort. For a more specific answer: On what language(s), framework(s) and/or libraries is the application based? Does it contain native binary code? What build system does it use?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean with "the code". The binaries have to be compiled for the target architecture, so the *machine code* will differ for these two machines as AlexP pointed out. But the packages are usually based on the same *source code*, so applications of the same version should provide the same functionality and behaviour as far as supported by the hardware and the environment (depending on the available libs).

For a more detailed answer we need to know what [the intention of this question is](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: AlexP stated the Jetson tx2 is written in ARM assembly which I will be coding in because that is what I want to work thru it was just a stupid question something I didn't really think thru cause I knew that honestly.

Comment: @Asjawweege If my answer was still helpful it would be nice if you would upvote it, to keep the good karma flowing...